# Are pronoun-only suggested edits acceptable?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

On Chess.SE, there's a user who is [suggesting](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17111) [pronoun-only](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17005) [edits](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16961). And I mean [lots](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16950) [of](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16879) [edits](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16860). [Some](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17105) [even](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17084) [change](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16875) [quotes](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16831).

Is there an official policy regarding such edits? Should they be approved (improve the post) or rejected (no improvement whatsoever)?

---

- Originally posted on [Chess.SE Meta](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/924), but since I didn't get a reply and because this is not a site-specific issue, I asked it here, too.
- [Can the official FAQ be changed slightly with respect to editing old posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335025) is related but doesn't mention anything about suggested edits.

Comment: If they are wrong, they should rejected. There isn't anything wrong in using _he_ when referring to a male person or a person who said _he_ should be used to refer him. Those edits are just adding confusion.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336379/317773

Comment: @kiamlaluno question is what to do when the post is general and does not refer to a specific gender.

Comment: Of course, the post I linked doesn't address the point of someone going on to do mass edits...

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating If the user just edits pronouns when there is something else that needs to be fixed, the edits should be rejected. I am not even sure that editing the pronouns like that would always be the correct action to take.

Comment: What strikes me as odd that they even fix the pronouns in quotes from external resources, where the external resource simply isn't gender neutral written, at all.

Comment: @rene is correct, changing quote inside a post is wrong, period. It's like changing code on Stack Overflow: we just don't do it.

Comment: The edits are trivial and unsupported, it looks like [you are doing the correct thing](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17084); overall the person has so many rejections that the problem may correct itself shortly. --- To the general question: If ***any*** reason to review / flag / etc. is *correct* then it's not "wrong" to use it. --- Trivial edits are for those with editing privileges; who often spot additional improvements, pick *better* posts to bump, and don't bother the reviewers. -- Different sites, different (unofficial) policy about bumping; YMMV. -- Reject away.

Comment: @rene It's even more odd because nobody would write _[they]_ when referring to a person.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I would, when not knowing the person's gender. I was introduced to it on SE, and use it everywhere else now, with success. Read [this nice blog post about it](https://apastyle.apa.org/blog/singular-they). Times are changing.

Comment: @kiamlaluno oh, no. Thought you mean just "they". :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating No, that's not how I quote what a person says. (Times could be changing, but something is immutable.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think the editor uses [] to indicate that it's an edit from an 'outsider' and not part of the original text, as in changing *I think, while I consider a long phrase of irrelevant text that is going to be edited out for legibility, not* can be edited to *I think [....] not*

Comment: I noticed they're inclusive of other species too: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/74769

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well — your examples are being handled appropriately.

It is worth considering both the *spirit* and *letter* of the overall rules.

In cases where it is a specific person — I think the intent is to have the *correct* pronoun. Editing someone who is indisputably "he" or "she" to "they" certainly doesn't match the spirit of "call people by their correct pronouns". In many of these cases, considering that the people in question are public figures, looking them up should be trivial. Using the singular they here might be incorrect in many of these cases (though if it is correct, maybe adding the source to the edit summary is a great idea).

Likewise — where a text uses a specific set of gender specific pronouns — it is for the body that is writing it to choose to switch to a neutral set of pronouns. A quotation *is* a quotation, and ought to be exactly as the source is.

As such, a good chunk of the edits here are bogus and counter-productive and ought to be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

This was already discussed in [pronouns FAQ clarifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336379/233944) and looks reasonable:

> ### From Catija:
>
> There's two separate cases, which is, I think, where the struggle here
> lies. In all cases, **mass edits are bad**. Please don't seek out
> edits to make.
>
> 1. **A post speaks of a hypothetical or generic person.** In this case, unless the gender somehow matters to the post, being gender
>    neutral is beneficial.
>
> - Be very careful that the edits don't harm the post or make it confusing. This is particularly the case in code.
> - Be aware that *suggesting* pronoun-only edits should be acceptable but do be certain to correct more than just the pronouns. If there are
>   spelling, punctuation or grammatical errors, fix those, too.
>
> 2. **A post speaks of an actual person.** In this case, unless you know the pronouns are incorrect **AND** you know that the person is
>    generally known on Stack Exchange to have identified their pronouns,
>    do not make the gender neutral.
>
> - It's possible the poster actually knows the correct pronouns.
> - If you know their pronouns from elsewhere, disclosing them yourself can "out" them to a community where they wished to be anonymous.